# Broken nested tree angular mat tree

Tags: css, angular, material-ui

I have difficulty in solving UI issue of expanding tree on the last node it always giving excessive line from the node just like the picture below.
I tried to reduced the the left border height but it still got no change at all.
Does anyone has any ideas and how to solve this.

Many Thanks in Advance

Does anyone know why ?

[PICTURE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zK67j.png)

here's the code for the CSS

```
.tree-nested-node {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

mat-tree {
  margin-left: 18px;
}
.mat-tree-node {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.mat-nested-tree-node {
  top: -24px;
}

ul, li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li.tree-container {
  border-bottom: 0;
  /*display: block;*/
}

ul {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

li {
  padding-left: 10px;
  border: dotted grey;
  border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
}

li.mat-tree-node,
li div {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 24px;
}

li ul {
  border-top: 1px dotted grey;
  margin-left: -10px;
  padding-left: 28px;
}

.mat-nested-tree-node:last-child ul {
  border-left: 0;
  margin-left: -10px;
}


td.node-number {
  width: 90px !important;
  text-align: right !important;
}

td.node-icon {
  width: 30px !important;
  text-align: center !important;
}

table.node-box {
  width: 100%;
}

 <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChildren">
        <li class="tree-container">
          <div class="mat-tree-node">
            <aten-hierarchy-tree-node [hierarchyNode]="node"
                                      (onCollapsingNode)="collapseNode($event)"
                                      (onExpandingNode)="expandNode($event)">
            </aten-hierarchy-tree-node>
          </div>
          <ul class="tree-nested-node">
            <div *ngIf="treeControl.isExpanded(node)">
              <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
              <div style="height: 34px;"></div>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </li>
  </mat-nested-tree-node>
```

Comment: "just like the picture below" there is no picture.

Comment: @CedricMoore I have added the link thanks for commenting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by fixing this to

```
.mat-nested-tree-node:last-child ul {
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  margin-left: -11px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `.tree-nested-node` there is a `padding-left of 30px`, now every nested item gets this padding and because nested items are actually **inside** each other, the padding stacks with every nested item (e.g. 30px for level 1, 30px + 30px for level 2, 30px + 30px + 30px for level 3 and so on).

What you want to do is to get rid of this padding, and give it to the root container element which seems to be `.tree-container` in your case.

```css
.tree-nested-node {
  // padding-left: 30px; <- get rid of this
  padding-left: 0;
}

.tree-container {
  padding-left: 30px; // <- add it here so it doesn't stack
}
```

Comment: I changed it become like this now
https://ibb.co/n8NzVZk

Comment: Then try removing the padding from both selectors then.

Comment: still the same result just like the picture in the question

Comment: I solved it by changing 

.mat-nested-tree-node:last-child ul {
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  margin-left: -11px;
  z-index: 10;
}

Comment: Aight, then; good for you : )